# Positive bases with respect to another fixed base

Tags: lie-algebras, root-systems

Let $\Delta$ be a base of a root system, i.e. a subset of a root system $ E =span \phi$ with $E$ Euclidean space, such that $\Delta$ is a basis of $E$ and every root can be written as a linear combination of elements of $\Delta$ with coefficients either all positive or negative. Suppose $\Delta_1$ and $\Delta_2$ are other two bases, positive with respect to $\Delta$. Is is true that $\Delta_1 = \Delta_2$? If so, why?

Comment: It is true that $\Delta = \Delta_1 = \Delta_2$, actually every positive system of roots contains a unique basis, namely, those positive roots which cannot be written as sum of two other positive roots. How to prove this depends on what you already know about root systems. So what are we allowed to use at this point?

Comment: In any case, e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1443709/ and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1322460/96384 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/601843/96384 are highly related.

Comment: Thank you. I am reading Humphreys "Introduction to Lie algebras and representations", so we are allowed to use everything in the related chapters.